# How to get the Prefabs position in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate tank face to moving enemy direction, and I need position of `enemy`.

`enemy.transform.position;` works when enemy is in the Hierarchy,  but my enemy is in the Prefabs and following code not work. please help  :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateTank : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject enemy;

void Update () {
    faceTank ();
}

void faceTank(){

    Vector3 enemyPosition;

    enemyPosition = enemy.transform.position;


    Vector2 direction = new Vector2 (
                             enemyPosition.x - transform.position.x,
                             enemyPosition.y - transform.position.y

                         );

    transform.up = direction;
}
}
```

Comment: A prefab doesn't have a position in the world, you need to reference to an entity that actual is instantiated (so you need to figure out which `enemy` your script is trying to target)

Comment: @UnholySheep I have one enemy and  I drag and drop in to the `Enemy` script : https://imgur.com/mEskmX8

Comment: I repeat: you are referencing a *Prefab* but you want to reference the gameobject that is instantiated in the world. You need to write some code to find said `GameObject` in the world

Answer (score 2):

A prefab does not exist in the game world. Prefabs are "templates" that can be instantiated. If what you want to do is make your tank rotate towards **any** enemy that exists in the game world, you'll need to reference those GameObjects in your RotateTank script. You could do this a number of ways, such as adding an 'Enemy' tag to your enemy prefab and using [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) to find spawned Enemies. You could also have a static `List<GameObject>` in your `RotateTank` script that holds references to existing enemies, and add them to that list when they spawn and remove them when they die.